# Itext change bookmarks zoom level to inherit zoom in existing pdf

Tags: java, itext

Using the **iText5** PDF library, I am able to **read bookmarks** exist in PDF. Now I want to change the `zoom level of bookmarks` (Inherit zoom) in existing PDF using iText.
Is it possible using the iText PDF library, and how?

I have attached a screenshot.
[image]

This is the code I am using to change the bookmark zoom level (as per @lowagie comment):

```
public void changeList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        for (HashMap<String, Object> entry : list) {
            for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key);

                if ("Kids".equals(key)) {
                    Object o = entry.get(key);
                    changeList((List<HashMap<String, Object>>) o);
                } else if ("Page".equals(key)) {
                    String dest = (String) entry.get(key);
                    entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("Fit", "XYZ 30 100 0"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Bookmark Tree Structure :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at my answer to the following question: [Set inherit Zoom(action property) to bookmark in the pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217657/set-inherit-zoomaction-property-to-bookmark-in-the-pdf-file)

In that answer, I read bookmarks using the `SimpleBookmark` object. That's probably the same way you are reading bookmarks. The result is a `List` of `HashMap` objects that represents an outline tree. I use a recursive method to find all the `"Page"` entries.

These page entries contain a destination, for instance `Fit`, `FitH`, `XYZ`,... You need to change all these references into `XYZ` references of which you set the zoom factor to 0. A zoom factor 0 is the equivalent of 'Inherit Zoom'.

In my answer to [Set inherit Zoom(action property) to bookmark in the pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217657/set-inherit-zoomaction-property-to-bookmark-in-the-pdf-file) I had this code:

```
public void changeList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> entry : list) {
        for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
            if ("Kids".equals(key)) {
                Object o = entry.get(key);
                changeList((List<HashMap<String, Object>>)o);
            }
            else if ("Page".equals(key)) {
                String dest = (String)entry.get(key);
                entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("Fit", "FitV 60"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's obvious that you can replace any existing "Page" action by a completely new action. For instance:

```
entry.put("Page", "XYZ 30 100 0");
```

Now you'll jump to the coordinate 30 100 on the page with an inherited zoom factor. If you want to zoom in on another part, for instance a location that corresponds more or less with the original location, you need to examine the coordinates that followed the `FitR` in your original PDF. There are 4: the lower-left x, lower-left y, upper-right x and upper-right y coordinate. You could parse the string with the original destination for those values and reuse two of these coordinates as your X and Y values in the `XYZ` destination.

The X Y coordinate passed with the XYZ destination is the coordinate of the top-left corner. For instance, if you have `FitR -3 234 486 627`, then you zoom in on a rectangle with coordinates llx = -3, lly = 234, urx = 486 and ury = 627 (ll refers to lower-left; ur refers to upper-right). The top left corner is llx,ury or in your case x = -3 and y = 627. In short: in this case, you'd need "XYZ -3 627 0".

Comment: Zoom level in some bookmark is Custom, how can i make it inherit zoom?

Comment: If i open my pdf file in notpad++ editor, i found **FitR**( before changing bookmark level)

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have tried code(added in question)- but unable to work in some file( specially when zoom level is custom).

Comment: I want to see that PDF, so that I can prove that either my answer is correct, or the PDF is not what you pretend it to be.

Comment: Note that `FitR` refers to "fit rectangle", which means you don't define a `z` value as a zoom factor but a rectangle to zoom into. If you want "Inherit zoom", you need `XYZ` followed by 3 parameters: an x value, a y value and 0 for the zoom value. You're not telling me anywhere if you understood this. You're not telling me what you found *after* changing the bookmarks.

Comment: Your answer is correct. but if the bookmark property is custom unable to make it inherit zoom in some case. or can i change FitR to XYZ.

Comment: Can you provide your email id ,so i can send you PDF file.

Comment: If i change bookmark i found nothing in bookmark property(action),  no zoom level.

Comment: It should be obvious that not every bookmark has a zoom level. Zoom levels can only be defined for XYZ destinations. Did you study any of the documents that are available?

Comment: That was implied in my answer. Note that people on SO are here to answer technical questions, not to do other people's homework. If I had just posted the code that solved *a specific problem*, this wouldn't have been interesting for other users. On SO, *generic answers* are preferred. As my answer is correct, you should accept it. Note that your colleague has succeeded where you fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217657/set-inherit-zoomaction-property-to-bookmark-in-the-pdf-file#comment37454562_24217767

Comment: Also: (1) asking people's personal e-mail is **not done on StackOverflow**, and (2) it's hard to believe somebody wouldn't be able to find my e-mail ;-)

Comment: if i use like entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("FitR", "XYZ 30 100 0"));. it set inherit zoom but when i click on bookmark unable to reach at desired location.

Comment: When you pick "XYZ 30 100 0", you tell the PDF that your desired location has the coordinate 30 100. Are you saying that 30 100 is **not** your desired location? If so, why don't you define your desired location?

Comment: Can i get bookmark top,left value and set it with XYZ.

Comment: I updated my answer explaining that you can find those coordinates right after the `"FitR"` in your original bookmarks. You have the coordinate of the lower-left and upper-right coordinate of the rectangle that was used as zoom area. Please accept the answer or I'll stop giving you advise.

Comment: I found Dest value like FitR -3 234 486 627. which value i have to use as x and y so destination will not get disturb?? sorry but last.

Comment: The X Y coordinate passed with the XYZ destination is the coordinate of the top-left corner. If you currently zoom in on llx = -3, lly = 234, urx = 486 and ury = 627, the top left corner is llx,ury or in your case x = -3 and y = 627. In short: you need "XYZ -3 627 0".

Comment: I have one more problem regarding hyper link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260323/itext-change-zoom-level-of-all-hyper-link-to-inherit-zoom-in-existing-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't help you out if you must do it with iText. But if you just want to change the zoom level of your bookmarks, you can also use the [PDF Clown](http://pdfclown.org) library, which I personally like a lot (especially when it comes to API design compared with iText).

Check out [this](https://bitbucket.org/beatngu13/pdfbookmarkwizard) small Java application I wrote, that does exactly what you want. The `Wizard` class gives you an overview on how to the change the zoom level. Basically you can achieve this with:

```
private void modifyBookmarks(Bookmarks bookmarks) {
    for (Bookmark bm : bookmarks) {
        if (!bm.getBookmarks().isEmpty()) {
            modifyBookmarks(bm.getBookmarks());
        }

        if (bm.getTarget() instanceof GoToDestination<?>) {
            Destination dest = ((GoToDestination<?>) 
                    bm.getTarget()).getDestination();
            dest.setMode(ModeEnum.XYZ);
            dest.setZoom(0.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, both (the tool and the library). Check out [org.bitbucket.beatngu13.pdfbookmarkwizard.core.Wizard](https://bitbucket.org/beatngu13/pdfbookmarkwizard/src/0b30973ce9c135809c9bdbffb61e1bb577c0a942/PDFBookmarkWizard/src/org/bitbucket/beatngu13/pdfbookmarkwizard/core/Wizard.java?at=master) to see how to apply various zoom levels to your bookmarks.

Comment: Actually my project build with java 1.5,does it possible in my project? because library compile with java 6...

Comment: I have try using old version of library, but no method to set zoom level

Comment: There is a [help forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/discussion/607163/) where you can ask library-specific questions like this.

Comment: Thanks @beatngu , can i change magnification using this library

Comment: What exactly do you mean by magnification? As far as I know you can set this property for link or bookmark destinations. You can check out the [API](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/) for details (have a look at *org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.actions.GoToDestination<T>* and *org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.navigation.document.Destination*).

Comment: i want to set property of internal hyperlink to inherit zoom.

Comment: That should be possible. Again, check the [API](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/) and study *org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.Link*.

Comment: Done...... Thanks, one more problem i am facing is to change page layout property to default. there is method document.setPageLayout(...) but unable to set default