# itext change zoom level of all hyper link to inherit zoom in existing pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using following code to change zoom level of all hyperlinks to **inherit zoom**, but unable to change.

may be i have made some mistake in PdfName.DEST and condition because there is no array of DEST in pdf for first page( check out screen shot).

```
for (int count = 0; count < reader.getNumberOfPages(); count++) {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(count+1);
        PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annots != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < annots.size(); i++) {
                PdfDictionary annotation = annots.getAsDict(i);
                if (PdfName.LINK.equals(annotation.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
                     if(annotation.get(PdfName.A)==null){
                          continue;
                     }
                    PdfArray d = annotation.getAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
                    if (d != null && d.size() == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.equals(d.getAsName(1)))
                        d.set(4, new PdfNumber(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created link in first page to second page, check out structure in image.

[image]

I have also try to use following code... i have debug and check value of **d** is null every time

```
for (int count = 0; count < reader.getNumberOfPages(); count++) {
            PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(count+1);
            PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            if (annots != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < annots.size(); i++) {
                    PdfDictionary annotation = annots.getAsDict(i);
                    if (PdfName.LINK.equals(annotation.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {

                        PdfArray d = annotation.getAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
                        // d is null every time
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a screen shot that allows you to look inside the PDF. In this screen shot, you clearly see that the destination is `[5 0 R, /FitH, 795]`. However, you only change the zoom factor of destinations that consist of 5 values and that are of type `/XYZ`.

```
 if (d != null && d.size() == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.equals(d.getAsName(1)))
      d.set(4, new PdfNumber(0));
```

`[5 0 R, /FitH, 795]` has 3 elements (in other words `d.size() == 5` is `false`) and the first entry in the array is `PdfName.FITH` (in other words `PdfName.XYZ.equals(d.getAsName(1)` is false).

Your question should be down-voted because you show one thing, then do something else, and then ask us why you don't get the expected result. It's as if somebody serves you soup and you see a spoon and a fork on the table. In spite of the fact that you know that soup should be eaten with a spoon, you take the fork and then complain that you can't eat soup with a fork. That's... odd.

**Update** In the comments, you complain that `d` is `null`, but looking at your screen shot, you already knew that `d` is null.

You loop over the pages and you get the page dictionary for page 1 (Object 4). You check if there's an `/Annots` entry in this page dictionary. There is (object 40). You loop over the annots and you encounter an annotation dictionary (object 30 or 39, the resolution of the screen shot is too bad for me to see). You check if the `/Subtype` is `Link`. It is. You check if the annotation has an `/A` entry. It has. Then you get the `/Dest` entry. There is no such entry. Hence you get `null`. The destination is to be found here:

```
PdfDictionary action = annotation.get(PdfName.A);
if (action != null) {
    PdfArray d = action.getAsArray(PdfName.D);
    // now examine and change D
}
```

Note that you are asking the SO community to write your application in your place. You are paid for this solution, but you expect that other people do your work in your place. Moreover: you probably don't have a commercial license for iText...

Comment: Actually i want to change all links properties to inherit zoom. sorry but i am bad in English.

Comment: i also get null in d  before that condition.

Comment: PdfArray d = annotation.getAsArray(PdfName.DEST); always return null.

Comment: PdfDictionary action = annotation.get(PdfName.A); --- ClassCast Exception

Comment: i am using itext for my small semester project. that's why i have not commercial licence of itext.

Comment: I am getting .. [6 0 R, /FitH, 796] in d

Comment: Aha, so you're abusing my patience so that I do your homework in your place? That's against the rules on StackOverflow. It also explains why two different people are asking the exact same questions. The goal of doing homework is learning. You don't learn anything if somebody else makes your homework in your place. You say "I am getting [6 0 R, /FitH, 796]" That's exactly what I say (although I thought it was `5 0 R` due to the bad resolution of the screen shot). If you read https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/ you know that `FitH` means "Fit horizontally at y = 796".

Comment: if i use d.set(1, PdfName.XYZ);d.set(4, new PdfNumber(1)); it make link to inherit zoom. but destination disturb. i know there is three parameters of XYZ but when i try to set in i get array index out of bound exception.