# Changing zoom in links in PDF files

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I would like to write some code that changes zoom in links in case of `/Fit`. I've come up with some code that shows value `/Fit` and changes it to `XYZ 0 0 1` for 100% zoom, but the result PDF has still zoom of type `/Fit`. [Here](https://www.upload.ee/files/6969501/selection.pdf.html) you can find my sample PDF.

```
PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
PdfArray annotationsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
if (annotationsArray == null)
    continue;


for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++)
{
    PdfDictionary annotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);
    PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
    if (annotationAction == null)
        continue;

    if (PdfName.GOTO.Equals(annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S)))
    {
        PdfArray d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D);
        if (d.Length == 15)
        {
            d[1] = new PdfString("XYZ 0 0 1");
            //Console.WriteLine(d[1]); // shows /Fit for my sample PDF
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Upon a request of @mkl, I paste my code that aims to change zoom in all kind of links in PDF files. By trial-and-error, I've found that arrays that hold information on zoom factor could be of size `15` and `30`. Please see my code to find out how I arrived at that numbers. Additionally, [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281784/2657875) has once written, zoom factor of links in PDF could be of 3 and 5 elements.

> ... zoom factor of destinations that consist of 5 values and that
>   are of type /XYZ
>
> ... `[5 0 R, /FitH, 795]` has 3 elements (in other words `d.size() == 5` is
>   false)

[Sample pdfs](https://www.upload.ee/files/6989627/Debug.zip.html)

My code:

```
public static void ChangeZoomOfLinks(PdfReader reader, double zoom = 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
        PdfArray annotationsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annotationsArray == null)
            continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);
            PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
            if (annotationAction == null)
                continue;

            if (PdfName.GOTO.Equals(annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S)))
            {
                PdfArray d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D);
                if (d == null)
                    continue;

                // for custom zoom type, e.g. 100 
                if (d.Length == 30)     //  this length is in: lock.pdf
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Custom zoom of: {0}. Table length: {1}", d[4], d.Length);
                    d[4] = new PdfNumber(zoom);
                }
                // for Fit zoom
                else if (d.Length == 15) // this length is in: tony.pdf
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Custom zoom of: {0}. Table length: {1}", d[1], d.Length);
                    d[1] = new PdfString("XYZ 0 0 2");
                }
            }
            // below is ported code of Bruno Lowagie
            else if (PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S)))
            {
                PdfArray d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
                if (d != null && d.Length == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(d[4]);
                    d[4] = new PdfNumber(zoom);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are wondering why no one answers here: The links in your sample document are broken, so how could anyone help you. That been said, the condition `d.Length == 15` in your code is weird, why should that array ever have 15 elements? And even if you for some reason got into the body of that `if` clause, why do you try to put that string `"XYZ 0 0 1"` into a single array element there while the specification expects 4 array elements: the name **XYZ** and 3 numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me start with '15' being a "magic number": in my sample PDF (yes, I know now it's broken) many arrays have 15 elements. How did I know this?  I made my code to write the length of each array ( 'd.Length') associated with each link and that way I got that number. (If you run my code against the sample PDF, you would probably get the same result). Why string? I did read the specification and so XYZ and 3 numbers as you wrote. Hence I wrote "XYZ 0 0 1". I'm still learning `C#` and that's the reason why I'm making mistakes, perhaps even stupid.

Comment: If you are interested in asnwering my questions (or suggesting what should I do), please let me give some time (it's almost midnight where I live) and I will show you more of my code with some comments.

Comment: *"in my sample PDF (yes, I know now it's broken) many arrays have 15 elements. How did I know this? I made my code to write the length of each array ( 'd.Length') associated with each link and that way I got that number"* - That is weird, I did not see any **D** array of that size in your file.

Comment: *"Why string? I did read the specification and so XYZ and 3 numbers as you wrote. Hence I wrote "XYZ 0 0 1". I'm still learning C# and that's the reason why I'm making mistakes,"* - Please read the specification more thoroughly - you add a PDF string object `"XYZ 0 0 1"` as second parameter but the PDF specification requires a second, third, fourth, and fifth parameter, a name **XYZ** and three numbers.

Comment: *"it's almost midnight where I live"* - here, too, so we likely live in the same time zone. I will shortly be offline, too, so take your time.

Comment: Great, I will write more tomorrow.

Comment: @mkl I updated my question.

Comment: I just wonder, in the same paragraph you say *"By trial-and-error, I've found that arrays that hold information on zoom factor could be of size **15** and **30**"* and *"Additionally, Bruno Lowagie has once written, zoom factor of links in PDF could be of 3 and 5 elements"* --- but *3 or 5* are clearly different from *15 or 30*...

Comment: Ah, ok. You clearly wrote `Length` in your code but I always thought about the `Size`. The length indeed is the number of characters used to represent that array inside the PDF file. This obviously can vary much, there may be additional white space inside, there may be numbers of arbitrary precision, etc. What you should use instead is the size, the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In a nutshell

The main issue in your code is that you try to set the destination array element `d[1]` to the *string* `"XYZ 0 0 2"` while you should have set `d[1]` to the *name* **XYZ**, `d[2]` and `d[3]` to the number `0`, and `d[4]` to the number `zoom`.

A side issue is that you try to determine the type of the destination array by its `Length`. This length actually is the *number of characters* used to represent that array inside the PDF file. This number obviously can vary much, there may be additional white space inside, there may be numbers of arbitrary precision, etc., so this is not a good criterion. What you should use instead is the `Size`, the *number of elements* in the array, in combination with the value of the second element.

#### Fixing your method

Thus, your method can be fixed like this

```
public static void ChangeZoomOfLinksFixed(PdfReader reader, double zoom = 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
        PdfArray annotationsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annotationsArray == null)
            continue;


        for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);
            PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
            if (annotationAction == null)
                continue;
            PdfName actionType = annotationAction.GetAsName(PdfName.S);

            PdfArray d = null;
            if (PdfName.GOTO.Equals(actionType))
                d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D);
            else if (PdfName.LINK.Equals(actionType))
                d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
            if (d == null)
                continue;

            // for custom zoom type
            if (d.Size == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} XYZ; former zoom {2}.", i, actionType, d[4]);
                d[4] = new PdfNumber(zoom);
            }
            // for Fit zoom
            else if (d.Size == 2 && PdfName.FIT.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} Fit.", i, actionType);
                d[1] = PdfName.XYZ;
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(0));
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(0));
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(zoom));
            }
            else if (d.Size > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} {2}. To be implemented.", i, actionType, d.GetAsName(1));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} {2}. Invalid.", i, actionType, d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have add additional `if` branches for invalid destinations (a valid destination array has at least 2 elements) and not yet implemented destination types as there are numerous destination types you do not yet consider.

#### Specified destination types

The PDF specification knows these destination types:

> **Syntax** Meaning
>
> **[*page* /XYZ *left top zoom*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the coordinates (*left*, *top*) positioned at the upper-left corner of the window and the contents of the page magnified by the factor *zoom*. A null value for any of the parameters *left*, *top*, or *zoom* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged. A *zoom* value of 0 has the same meaning as a null value.
>
> **[*page* /Fit]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit the entire page within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centering the page within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitH *top*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the vertical coordinate *top* positioned at the top edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire width of the page within the window. A null value for *top* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitV *left*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with the horizontal coordinate *left* positioned at the left edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire height of the page within the window. A null value for *left* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitR *left bottom right top*]**
>   Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit the rectangle specified by the coordinates *left*, *bottom*, *right*, and *top* entirely within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centering the rectangle within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitB]**
>   *(PDF 1.1)* Display the page designated by *page*, with its contents magnified just enough to fit its bounding box entirely within the window both horizontally and vertically. If the required horizontal and vertical magnification factors are different, use the smaller of the two, centering the bounding box within the window in the other dimension.
>
> **[*page* /FitBH *top*]**
>   *(PDF 1.1)* Display the page designated by *page*, with the vertical coordinate *top* positioned at the top edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire width of its bounding box within the window. A null value for *top* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> **[*page* /FitBV *left*]**
>   *(PDF 1.1)* Display the page designated by *page*, with the horizontal coordinate *left* positioned at the left edge of the window and the contents of the page magnified just enough to fit the entire height of its bounding box within the window. A null value for *left* specifies that the current value of that parameter shall be retained unchanged.
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 151 – Destination syntax)*

So there still are a number of cases to implement...

#### Fixing your method even further

As you observed the transformed **Fit** targets now jumped to the page *after* the original target if the **PageLayout** was **OneColumn**. Everything seemed ok for the **PageLayout** value **SinglePage**, though.

The cause is that we insert the coordinates (0,0) for the **XYZ** replacement of **Fit**. Looking into the quoted specification excerpt above we see that **XYZ** means that the page is to be displayed *with the given coordinates positioned at the **upper-left corner** of the window*! Usually, though, PDF pages have coordinate systems with the coordinate origin (0,0) in the **lower-left** corner of the page or even beneath.

Thus, what we interpreted as a jump to the following page actually is a jump where the bottom left of the target page is in the top left of the window... ;)

If we want to use more appropriate coordinates for the top left corner, we can extend the fixed method like this:

```
public static void ChangeZoomOfLinksFixedMore(PdfReader reader, double zoom = 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(i);
        PdfArray annotationsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annotationsArray == null)
            continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < annotationsArray.Size; j++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotation = annotationsArray.GetAsDict(j);
            PdfDictionary annotationAction = annotation.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
            if (annotationAction == null)
                continue;
            PdfName actionType = annotationAction.GetAsName(PdfName.S);

            PdfArray d = null;
            if (PdfName.GOTO.Equals(actionType))
                d = annotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D);
            else if (PdfName.LINK.Equals(actionType))
                d = annotation.GetAsArray(PdfName.DEST);
            if (d == null)
                continue;
            if (d.Size < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} {2}. Invalid.", i, actionType, d);
                continue;
            }

            float left = 0;
            float top = 0;
            PdfObject pageObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObjectRelease(d[0]);
            if (pageObject is PdfDictionary)
            {
                PdfArray cropBox = ((PdfDictionary)pageObject).GetAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
                if (cropBox == null)
                    cropBox = ((PdfDictionary)pageObject).GetAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
                if (cropBox != null && cropBox.Size == 4)
                {
                    if (cropBox[0] is PdfNumber)
                        left = ((PdfNumber)cropBox[0]).FloatValue;
                    if (cropBox[3] is PdfNumber)
                        top = ((PdfNumber)cropBox[3]).FloatValue;
                }
            }

            // for custom zoom type
            if (d.Size == 5 && PdfName.XYZ.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} XYZ; former zoom {2}.", i, actionType, d[4]);
                d[4] = new PdfNumber(zoom);
            }
            // for Fit zoom
            else if (d.Size == 2 && PdfName.FIT.Equals(d.GetAsName(1)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} Fit.", i, actionType);
                d[1] = PdfName.XYZ;
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(left));
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(top));
                d.Add(new PdfNumber(zoom));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Page {0} {1} {2}. To be implemented.", i, actionType, d.GetAsName(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware, this does not yet consider all corner cases: The **CropBox** or **MediaBox** may be inherited from an ancestor node in the page tree, that box array might not be ordered in the usual manner, or the entries of that array might be indirect objects.

Comment: _you try to determine the type of the destination array by its Length._ If it hadn't been for you, I wouldn't have spotted this. Thanks! _So there still are a number of cases to implement._ And that's great. I'll have to do this on my own and hence I'll learn more. Could you elaborate more on the section of your code that starts with `PdfArray d = null;` and ends with `continue;`? Your code is self-explanatory but I find this portion a little hard to follow.

Comment: One more thing: when link zoom is changed by the `for Fit zoom` section, the number (page number) to jump to is increased by one, so the link jumps to incorrect (increased by one) page. Your code doesn't seem to do that (I debugged this) and there seems to be a bug in `iTextSharp`. Am I missing something? Could you run the code against lock.pdf (sample PDF I gave link to)?

Comment: *"Could you elaborate more on the section of your code that starts with `PdfArray d = null;` and ends with `continue;`?"* - that essentially is a compressed version of your code. A GoTo action has its destination as value of **D** in the action and Link had its destination as value of **Dest** in the annotation. If the action is neither or the retrieved destination is null, there is nothing to do.

Comment: Now it clear. How about destinations being increased by one?

Comment: Could you have a look at the matter I described above, please?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your observation: I applied `ChangeZoomOfLinksFixed` to all pages of lock.pdf, once with zoom 1, once with zoom 10, and in both cases the links led to the right page when used in Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: My fault. It wasn't `lock.pdf` but [that](https://www.upload.ee/files/6995498/entity.rar.html) file. The error persists with the latest version of `iTexSharp`, i.e. `5.5.11` and with `5.5.10`. Could you also check it, please?

Comment: Even with your new file I cannot reproduce the issue. Again using zoom values 1 and 10, I'm always pushed to the correct page by Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: It was fault of Foxit PhantomPDF. It is jumping to incorrect page even thought the produced PDF is OK.

Comment: *grin* ... that's why I prefer to add the information on which viewer I do or do not observe some behavior...

Comment: Adobe Acrobat XI and SumatraPDF also jump to incorrect page even thought the fixed method doesn't change the number of page to jump to. [Here](https://www.upload.ee/files/6998179/Debug.rar.html) you can find my compiled program and produced PDF.

Comment: There is another difference: Your code appears to additionally change the **PageLayout** from **SinglePage** to **OneColumn**. With that change in place I can also reproduce the issue, without it not.

Comment: You're right. Is it issue with my code or with `iTextSharp` itself?

Comment: Cf. the new section "Fixing your method even further" in my answer. The issue is with the coordinates (0,0) the code uses with the **XYZ** destination...

Comment: Great, now it looks impressive!