# iTextSharp get Actions from Table Of Content PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tableofcontents

I have a PDF with a TOC:

[image: Table of Contents]

Using the iTextSharp.dll I'm trying to get the annotations then the actions on these annotations. Then I want to manipulate/change the link to point to another page. For example if **Chapter 1** in the TOC points to page 5 I would like it to point to page 2 when I click on the link. For some reason the action on the annotation is null and therefore I can not manipulate this data. The code below works but keeps providing a null **action**. I don't understand why that is.
To reproduce the pdf in question

- create a word document with 3 pages
- Page 1 will be the table of contents, Page 2 Chapter 1, Page 3 Chapter 2
- export to PDF
- Once you have the PDF the TOC should be 'clickable'.

I would then like to be able to manipulate where it clicks to. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace PDFLinks
{
    class Program
    {
        //Folder that we are working in
        //private static readonly string WorkingFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Hyperlinked PDFs");
        //Sample PDF
        private static readonly string BaseFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Temp", "TableOfContentsTest.pdf");
        //Final file
        private static readonly string OutputFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Temp", "NewFile.pdf");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Setup some variables to be used later
            PdfReader R = default(PdfReader);
            int PageCount = 0;

            //Open our reader
            R = new PdfReader(BaseFile);
            //Get the page cont
            PageCount = R.NumberOfPages;
            Console.WriteLine("Page Count= " + PageCount);

            //Loop through each page
            //for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
            //{
                //Get the current page
                PdfDictionary PageDictionary = R.GetPageN(1);
                //Get all of the annotations for the current page
                PdfArray Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
                //Make sure we have something
                if ((Annots == null) || (Annots.Length == 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
                }

                //Loop through each annotation
                if (Annots != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ANNOTS Not Null" + Annots[0]);
                    foreach (PdfObject A in Annots.ArrayList)
                    {
                        //Convert the itext-specific object as a generic PDF object
                        PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);                    
                        //Make sure this annotation has a link
                        if (!AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK))
                            continue;
                        //Make sure this annotation has an ACTION
                        if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) == null)
                            continue;
                        if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) != null) 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ACTION Not Null");
                        }
                        //Get the ACTION for the current annotation
                        PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);

                        // Test if it is a URI action (There are tons of other types of actions,
                        // some of which might mimic URI, such as JavaScript,
                        // but those need to be handled seperately)
                        if (AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
                        {
                            PdfString Destination = AnnotationAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI);
                            string url1 = Destination.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
           //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: providing a link to a file that would reproduce the problem right away will increase your chances compared to listing the steps with no formatting

Comment: This happens to any file. Create a word with a TOC and convert it to PDF.

Comment: Links can have **Destinatoons** instead of actions...

Comment: @mkl please elaborate, can you provide the path to get to the destination please?

Comment: @AlfonsoCaruana As elaborating that in a comment is difficult, I did so in an answer, see below.

Comment: @mkl Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Dest**inations

In your **Link** annotations you only look for an **A**ction entry but there alternatively may be a **Dest**ination entry, cf. the PDF specification ISO 32000-2:

> **A**
>   dictionary
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.1)* An action that shall be performed when the link annotation is activated (see 12.6, "Actions").
>
> **Dest**
>   array, name or byte string
>   *(Optional; not permitted if an **A** entry is present)* A destination that shall be displayed when the annotation is activated (12.3.2, "Destinations").

*(ISO 32000-2 Table 176 — Additional entries specific to a link annotation)*

There are a number of types of destinations, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43864121/1729265), in particular the specification quote there, but the code there handling some of those types may also be of interest.

### **A**ctions

Even for **Link**s with **A**ctions, you only consider ***a)*** the first action and ***b)*** actions of type **URI**.

#### Multiple actions

**Link**s can trigger a sequence of actions, the follow-up actions being referenced from the first action, cf. the specification

> **Next**
>   dictionary or array
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.2)* The next action or sequence of actions that shall be performed after the action represented by this dictionary. The value is either a single action dictionary or an array of action dictionaries that shall be performed in order; see Note 1 for further discussion.
>
> NOTE 1 The action dictionary’s **Next** entry (PDF 1.2) allows sequences of actions to be chained together. For example, the effect of clicking a link annotation with the mouse might be to play a sound, jump to a new page, and start up a movie. Note that the **Next** entry is not restricted to a single action but may contain an array of actions, each of which in turn may have a **Next** entry of its own. The actions may thus form a tree instead of a simple linked list.

*(ISO 32000-2 Table 196 — Entries common to all action dictionaries)*

As the example in the NOTE implies, the jump to a new page need not be the first action of a **Link**, so for your task you should definitively inspect all the actions of your **Link**.

#### Action types

> A **uniform resource identifier** (URI) is a string that identifies (resolves to) a resource on the Internet — typically a file that is the destination of a hypertext link, although it may also resolve to a query or other entity. (URIs are described in *Internet RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax.*)
>
> A *URI* action causes a URI to be resolved.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 12.6.4.8 URI actions)*

Thus, *URI* actions are quite unlikely to be found in the TOC of a PDF. You had better look for *GoTo* actions.

> A *go-to action* changes the view to a specified destination (page, location, and magnification factor). "Table 202 — Additional entries specific to a go-to action" shows the action dictionary entries specific to this type of action.
>
> NOTE Specifying a go-to action in the **A** entry of a link annotation or outline item (see "Table 176 — Additional entries specific to a link annotation" and "Table 151 — Entries in an outline item dictionary") has the same effect as specifying the destination directly with the **Dest** entry.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 12.6.4.2 Go-To actions)*

> **D**
>   name, byte string, or array
>   *(Required)* The destination to jump to (see 12.3.2, "Destinations").

*(ISO 32000-2 Table 202 — Additional entries specific to a go-to action)*

When inspecting *GoTo* actions, therefore, you eventually have to deal with the same kind of target specifications as when inspecting immediate link destinations discussed at the top of the answer.